# Can't build latest libcurl on RHEL 7.3

Tags: gcc, libcurl, rhel7

What's the proper way to fix this compilation error so I can install the latest libcurl on RHEL 7.3?

I've been able to get the latest openssl, build, and install it. `OpenSSL 1.1.1-dev  xx XXX xxxx` is reported by `openssl version` now. Latest curl is cloned/pulled from `https://github.com/curl/curl.git`. Here's the bash script fragment I'm using:

```
CD=$(pwd)
CPPFLAGS="-I$CD/zlib -I$CD/openssl -I$CD/openssl/include" 
LDFLAGS="-L$CD/zlib -L$CD/openssl" 
LIBS="-ldl" 
cd curl
./buildconf
./configure --disable-shared --with-zlib --with-ssl
make
make install
```

Running the batch with `sudo`, `make` completes without errors. `make install` produces this:

```
  CC       libcurl_la-openssl.lo
vtls/openssl.c: In function 'Curl_ossl_seed':
vtls/openssl.c:279:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'RAND_egd' [-
Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   int ret = RAND_egd(data->set.str[STRING_SSL_EGDSOCKET]?
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [libcurl_la-openssl.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/john/curl/lib'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/john/curl/lib'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Oh man this is the 10th post I've seen today about libcurl not building :(

Comment: Probably a missing #include directive in vtls/openssl.c.

Comment: @arboreal84 I also pulled several older releases before posting this, and got similar blocking errors on RHEL 7.3. You still consider this a curl config issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Updated with cleaner version
Here's steps for building `curl` with the latest `openssl`

```
CD=$(pwd)
echo Setting up openssl
if [ ! -d openssl ]; then
    git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
    cd openssl
else
    cd openssl
    git pull
fi
# you may not need -Wl,--enable-new-dtags but it works for me
./config -Wl,--enable-new-dtags --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
make depend
make 
sudo make install
cd ..

lib=zlib-1.2.11
echo Setting up zlib
if [ ! -d zlib ]; then
    wget http://zlib.net/$lib.tar.gz
    tar xzvf $lib.tar.gz
    mv $lib zlib
fi
cd zlib
./configure
make
cd ..

echo Setting up curl ...
CD=$(pwd)

if [ ! -d curl ]; then
    git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git
    cd curl
else
    cd curl
    git pull
fi

cd curl
./buildconf
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig LIBS="-ldl" ./configure --with-
zlib=$CD/zlib --disable-shared
make
# I use local curl build without installing it
# make install
cd ..
```

I sincerely hope this helps someone else.

Comment: @DanielStenberg instead of voting down my answer, it would have been better for you to provide a more correct answer. However, I have updated my answer with a newer, clean solution I'm sure you will now upvote.

Answer (score 4):

RAND_egd() is no longer part of the default OpenSSL install. See [this git commit](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/0423f812dc61f70c6ae6643191259ca9e5692c7f). You can fix the problem by adding `enable-egd` in the configure command.